# Is there any way to start a flow on a node without rpc

Tags: corda

I would like to run a kafka consumer inside of a cordapp as a service, and start flows in response to messages. Can I do this without basically forking corda and exposing the node local rpcops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be supported in Corda V3 via the introduction of the `AppServiceHub` interface: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/AppServiceHub.kt.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered this by browsing master. Looks like a great feature. Is there any kind rough timetable for v3 being released?